# SonarQube - import rules from CodePro Analytix?

Tags: sonarqube

Currently evaluating SonarQube 3.7.2 as a possible successor for [CodeProAnalytix](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/).
Are there any tools for importing indvidual rules implemented for CodePro to SonarQube quality rules ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such tool doesn't exist, only checkstyle, pmd and findbugs configuration files can be imported.

Comment: Accepted - any chance for such a tool coming up ?